# Makefile for cuda/c++, Cannot successfully compile

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, cuda

I have spend quite some time trying to write a makefile to compile some c++ files along with some .cu files. I cannot successfully compile the target while I do get an output currently, it is not a proper binary file.

So, basically I have all my source files in a src directory, my makefile in the main project folder, one directory up from src. I have a main.cpp, a hostDeviceCom.cu, a myKernel.cu and a cudaErrorCheck.cu that I had tested in a previous project compiled by hand with nvcc in one step. The concept is to have a separate build folder where the .out will be.

So my question is: What am I doing so wrong in the following makefile?

```
TARGET_EXEC ?= cudaNestim.out
T_CUDA_O    ?= cudaTMp.o
NVCC        ?= nvcc
BUILD_DIR   ?= ./build
SRC_DIRS    ?= ./src
CUDA_ARCH   ?= -arch=sm_52
NVCCFLAGS   ?= $(CUDA_ARCH) 
NVCCFLNK    ?= $(CUDA_ARCH) --device-link
CXXFLAGS    ?= --std=c++11 -MM -MT
CXXOPTS     ?= -MM -MT
# System Libraries -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OCV_DIR     ?= -L/user/local/lib
OCV_LIB     ?= -lopencv_core -lopencv_viz -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc
OCV_INC     ?= -I/usr/include
OCV_LINK    ?= $(OCV_DIR) $(OCV_LIB)

CUDA_DIR    ?= -L/user/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
CUDA_LIB    ?= -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart 
CUDA_INC    ?= -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include
CUDA_LINK   ?= $(CUDA_DIR) $(CUDA_LIB)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# find all the source files
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cu -or -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.s) 
#go to build directory and create a .o file for each src file found
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
# create a .d file from each .o file. SO one .d for each .source
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)


LIB_DIRS := $(OCV_LINK) $(CUDA_LINK)
INCS     := $(CUDA_INC) $(OCV_INC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS) 
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLNK) $(OBJS) $(LIB_DIRS)  -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cu.o: %.cu
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< 

    #echo ".cu.o rule:" $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(OCV_INC) $(CUDA_INC)
    #$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(OCV_INC) $(CUDA_INC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCS) -o $@ -c $< 

# Phony rules -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p

-include $(DEPS)
```

I know, I am not using any .d rule, I am trying to make this work and figure out later how to incorporate a .d rule for more complex stuff.

Comment: Post the final linking command as it appears in your shell. Elaborate on "it is not a proper binary file.".

Comment: Also, what happens when you try to build the binary in two steps (objects first, then `cudaNestim.out`) by hand, without Make?

Answer (score 1):

> it is not a proper binary file

The proximal reason for this is that you are specifying device-link as the final build (ie link phase) operation:

```
NVCCFLNK    ?= $(CUDA_ARCH) --device-link
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
...

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS) 
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLNK) $(OBJS) $(LIB_DIRS)  -o $@ 
              ^^^^^^^^
```

As a result, the last build step you do is a device link, which [does not create an executable](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).  Your Makefile is generally also not set up properly for device-linking, because when separating compile from link, if you want device linking (i.e. generation of [relocatable device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda)) then you must specify `-dc`, not `-c` during compile:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cu.o: %.cu
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< 
                               ^^
```

Since you have already specified that the link phase should be done at once, and with `nvcc`, we can make [some relatively simple changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454960/unable-to-create-a-working-makefile-for-cuda-c-program/27464138#27464138) to your makefile to achieve a makefile that will do rdc linking.  Here's a fully worked example, derived from yours:

```
$ cat Makefile
TARGET_EXEC ?= cudaNestim.out
NVCC        ?= nvcc
BUILD_DIR   ?= ./bld
SRC_DIRS    ?= ./src
CUDA_ARCH   ?= -arch=sm_61
NVCCFLAGS   ?= $(CUDA_ARCH)
#NVCCFLNK    ?= $(CUDA_ARCH) --device-link
NVCCFLNK    ?= $(CUDA_ARCH)
CXXFLAGS    ?= --std=c++11 -MM -MT
CXXOPTS     ?= -MM -MT
# System Libraries -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OCV_DIR     ?= -L/user/local/lib
#OCV_LIB     ?= -lopencv_core -lopencv_viz -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc
OCV_LIB     ?=
OCV_INC     ?= -I/usr/include
OCV_LINK    ?= $(OCV_DIR) $(OCV_LIB)

CUDA_DIR    ?= -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
#CUDA_LIB    ?= -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart
CUDA_LIB    ?= -lcuda -lcudart
CUDA_INC    ?= -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include
CUDA_LINK   ?= $(CUDA_DIR) $(CUDA_LIB)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
# find all the source files
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cu -or -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.s)
#go to build directory and create a .o file for each src file found
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
# create a .d file from each .o file. SO one .d for each .source
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)


LIB_DIRS := $(OCV_LINK) $(CUDA_LINK)
INCS     := $(CUDA_INC) $(OCV_INC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
        $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLNK) $(OBJS) $(LIB_DIRS)  -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cu.o: %.cu
        $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
        $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -dc $<

    #echo ".cu.o rule:" $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(OCV_INC) $(CUDA_INC)
    #$(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(OCV_INC) $(CUDA_INC)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
        $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCS) -o $@ -c $<

# Phony rules -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)
$ ls
bld  Makefile  src
$ cat src/hello.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ void hello(){

  printf("hello!\n");
}
$ cat src/test.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ void hello();

__global__ void my_hello(){

  hello();
}

int main(){

  my_hello<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}
$ make clean
rm -f -r ./bld
$ make
mkdir -p bld/./src/
nvcc -arch=sm_61  -o bld/./src/hello.cu.o -dc src/hello.cu
mkdir -p bld/./src/
nvcc -arch=sm_61  -o bld/./src/test.cu.o -dc src/test.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_61 ./bld/./src/hello.cu.o ./bld/./src/test.cu.o -L/user/local/lib  -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart   -o bld/cudaNestim.out
$ bld/cudaNestim.out
hello!
$
```

Note that if you actually didn't want RDC code generation, you could change the `-dc` back to `-c` in the Makefile above.  However, for demonstration purposes, my particular code example depends on CUDA RDC.

Answer (score -2):

More of a suggestion than a direct answer:

What you're doing wrong is trying to reinvent the wheel. Use a higher-level build system, don't bother writing the Makefile yourself. There's more than one of these around; I personally use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and am sort-of happy with it. CMake has a module for setting up things paths and other variables for CUDA. Here's a short tutorial you could check out:

[How to build CUDA programs using CMake](https://codeyarns.com/2013/09/13/how-to-build-cuda-programs-using-cmake/)

Now, it's not that you'll never run into any issues, but:

1. There'll be less of them
2. They would likely be easier to debug (have look at some [CMake+CUDA questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda%20cmake?mode=all) here on SO).

Comment: To paraphrase JWZ -- use CMake instead. Now you have *two* problems.

Comment: @talonmies: Automatic the discovery of CUDA-related paths is something CMake will do for OP. So, no, now OP will have either 0 or 1 problems.